# Adding field to solr schema causing "no stream" error

Tags: curl, solr

I'm taking over a project and am having issues adding a field to a solr schema. According to the solr schema api I should be able to send a curl but I keep getting back this response:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
  "status":0,
  "QTime":0},
  "errors":"no stream"
}
```

Here is the request I am sending:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field":{"name":"information-description","type":"string","stored":true}}' http://dev-mywebsite.com:8983/solr/bdtest/schema
```

I did a bit of research and saw some posts advising to add `?commit=true` to my url; however, that is yielding the same result..

I also googled the error message and even searched the solr schema api docs but they don't seem to have response error messages listed anywhere.

**What is wrong with the curl I am sending to solr?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Solr you are using? Are you using the ClassicSchemaFactory or the ManagedIndexSchemaFactory?

If your config has a file named schema.xml then you are using the classic schema . factory. But Schema API can be used only with the ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.

If you have an existing Solr collection that uses ClassicIndexSchemaFactory, and you wish to convert to use a managed schema, you can simply modify the solrconfig.xml to specify the use of the ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.

You can read more about the [Schema Factory Definition in SolrConfig](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-factory-definition-in-solrconfig.html#schema-factory-definition-in-solrconfig)

Comment: SO didn't alert me to your answer till now. Thank you for responding. Let me check this out.

Comment: So it looks like this SOLR is using classic. Thanks again.