# Attempting to add new field type to Solr core causing "no stream" error

Tags: curl, solr

I'm using Solr 6.6.2 (with Sitecore, although I don't think that matters here) and am trying to add a new field type.

I have issued the following Curl command

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field-type":{"name":"text_semicolonDelimited","class":"solr.TextField","analyzer":{"tokenizer":{"class":"solr.PatternTokenizerFactory","pattern":";"}}}}' https://localhost:8983/solr/commerce_master/schema
```

which is intended to add a new field type.

I keep getting a "no stream" error. This is the full response:

```
{
"responseHeader":{
  "status":0,
  "QTime":0},
"errors":"no stream"}
```

Googling brings up [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088020/adding-field-to-solr-schema-causing-no-stream-error), which is similar, but the OP was using an older version of Solr which could circumvent the problem by editing the schema.xml file directly. For my version of Solr, it's advised not to do this.

Comment: Are you running the same on windows?

Comment: I'm running from a command window in Windows 10 to my local Solr instance.

Comment: Please check for the sytanx of curl on the windows..it should be double quotes

Comment: try this curl -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" --data-binary "{\"add-field-type\":{\"name\":\"text_semicolonDelimited\",\"class\":\"solr.TextField\",\"analyzer\":{\"tokenizer\":{\"class\":\"solr.PatternTokenizerFactory\",\"pattern\":\";\"}}}}" "https://localhost:8983/solr/commerce_master/schema"

Comment: Are you using the ClassicSchemaFactory or the ManagedIndexSchemaFactory?

Comment: If your config has a file named schema.xml then you are using the classic schema . factory. But Schema API can be used only with the ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.
If you have an existing Solr collection that uses ClassicIndexSchemaFactory, and you wish to convert to use a managed schema, you can simply modify the solrconfig.xml to specify the use of the ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I'm using Managed Schema, no schema.xml, just a managed-schema file with no extension. Thanks fro the pointer about the quotes

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti post your comment as an answer and I will happily accept it. Single quotes was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are executing the curl command on the windows environment, it should be wrapped with double quotes.

Use the below command and check.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" --data-binary "{\"add-field-type\":{\"name\":\"text_semicolonDelimited\",\"class\":\"solr.TextField\",\"analyzer\":{\"tokenizer\":{\"class\":\"solr.PatternTokenizerFactory\",\"pattern\":\";\"}}}}" "localhost:8983/solr/commerce_master/schema"
```